# Explanation about completeness and incompleteness theorems in logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, incompleteness

There must be some fundamental notion that I don't understand, because I have these doubts about Godel's completeness and incopleteness theorems in first order logic. The completeness theorem states that in a first order theory everything that is true is provable; the incompleteness theorem states that in the Robinson arithmetic (for example) there is a formula $A$ such that both $A$ and $\lnot A$ are not provable. Since one of $A$ and $\lnot A$ must be true, why it isn't true anymore that everything true is provable? Thanks in advance for your patience

Comment: The provable statements are those which are true with respect to every possible interpretation (universally true). If a statement is true with respect to some interpretation and false with respect to some interpretation , it is neither provable nor disprovable.

Comment: @Peter actually, when I say statement I mean a closed formula, so it's either true or not

Comment: "When I say statement I mean a closed formula, so it's either true or not". This is wrong, and I think it's the main source of your confusion. A sentence (closed formula) is either true or not *in a particular structure/model/interpretation*. In different structures, its truth value can be different. For example, is the sentence $\forall x\forall y\, (x\times y = y\times x)$ true? Well, it's true under some interpretations of $\times$ (e.g. multiplication of  natural numbers) but not under other interpretations (e.g. in a non-abelian group).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the use of the word "true".

- The completeness theorem says that $T$ proves $\varphi$ if and only if $\varphi$ is true *in all the models of $T$*.
- The incompleteness theorem says that there is $\varphi$ that is true *in a specific model, usually taken to be $\Bbb N$,* which is not provable from Robinson arithmetic.

Truth is always relative to a structure, but in the case of arithmetic, when we say "true" without qualifying it, we mean in the standard model: the natural numbers. But there are other models, and in those $\varphi$ will be false. Exactly because it is not provable from Robinson arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was exactly the issue, now I can clear out my ideas

Comment: Interesting. Then, could we say that the "incompleteness problem" arises because of the fact that no set of axioms (satisfying some minimum requirements) can uniquely describe the "platonic object" we want to describe, since there will always be non-standard models also satisfying those axioms, whatever axioms they are?

Comment: @BlackSwan: I mean, that's incredibly vague, but kinda (in the sense that any objection can be chucked into the "not satisfying the minimum requirements" as these weren't specified). At least if you mean the natural numbers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila By minimum requirements, I meant an effectively axiomatizable theory, "including at least arithmetic", etc.

Comment: @BlackSwan: Yes, I understand that.

Comment: Understanding that, my question is: the completeness theorem tells us that, in first order logic, a statement which is true in all models, this statement is provable. However, the incompleteness theorem tells us there are statements which are true in a specific model (the standard model of the natural numbers), but not in other models also satisfying the axioms. So, is it just this issue the "incompleteness problem"? That we cannot give precise axioms describing only the intended model (the natural numbers), and not other models?

Comment: @BlackSwan: This is not just about describing the intended model. Look at Th(N), all the true statements in the natural numbers. This theory is complete, although not recursively enumerable, but it still has non-standard models. Incompleteness is much more than categoricity (describing only a single model).

Answer (score 3):

"The completeness theorem states that in a first order theory everything that is true is provable." No it doesn't.

To say standard first order *logic* is complete is to say that if some premisses $\Gamma$ semantically entail a conclusion $\varphi$, then there is a formal proof from the premisses $\Gamma$ to the conclusion $\varphi$.

To say that a first order *theory* with axioms $\Gamma$ is (negation) incomplete is to say that there is some $\varphi$ such that $\Gamma$ entails neither $\varphi$ nor $\neg\varphi$.

It is obvious you can have an incomplete theory with a complete first-order logic (just omit some needed axioms from the theory).

What is not obvious, of course, but which we get from Gödel, is that some first order theories are in a good sense *incompletable*.

Any introductory text should explain this. Try for example my *Gödel Without (Too Many) Tears* which you can freely download from https://www.logicmatters.net/igt -- see page 6.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description of the incompleteness theorems for a layman:

Four words: provable, there exists a proof that an proposition is true; refutable, there exists a proof that an proposition is false; decidable, is said of a proposition that is either provable or refutable; undecidable, is said of a proposition that is neither provable nor refutable.

Incompleteness theorem 1: by formulating the following theorem "G: the theorem called G is not provable within the theory T", Gödel shows that G is necessarily undecidable, because G being provable leads to a contradiction and G being refutable leads to a contradiction.

Incompleteness theorem 2: a proof for the coherence of theory T is a proof that no proposition in T is both True and False. However, the existence of theorem G inside T makes this exercise of "knowing if it is not both True and False at the same time" impossible for G. Thus, there does not exist a proof of coherence for T; otherwise through this proof of coherence, one could know the truth value of G.

Comment: This isn't *that* inaccurate as far as for-the-layman summaries go, but still makes some conflations between truth and provability that cause more trouble than good imo (also, not sure why you use the term 'coherence' rather than the very standard term 'consistency'). But more to the point, this doesn't seem to answer the question at all.